Problema enfocar un carrito de compra sencillo con PHP y Javascript
Os comento el problema general y agradezco cualquier orientacion al respecto.
Tengo una base de datos con una tabla con productos, su nombre, su precio y unidades disponibles. Saco una lista de la base de datos haciendo un query (SELECT) desde PHP, que muestra la lista de los productos correctamente (muestra nº de articulo, nombre, precio). Ahora quiero que el usuario en un miniformulario escriba el numero de producto que desea y las unidades que quiere, y pulsa el boton "añadir a carrito".
Mi intencion es que una vez lo pulse, ese producto se vaya añadiendo y aparezca en un listado, en la misma pagina, en un div que he puesto al lado derecho, con su precio (ya sea dentro de una tabla o en un listado, no me importa. Este ultimo paso, no consigo hacer que funcione. Lo que hago es añadir al boton de añadir una funcion javascript que captura el valor de la etiqueta nº articulo, nombre y precio, y lo añade a una tabla, pero no me aparece nada en la tabla.


var productoelegido = document.getElementById("tablaprueba")
var numeroproductocesta = document.getElementById("numeroproducto").value;
var unidadescesta = document.getElementById("unidades").value;
document.getElementById("botoncarrito").addEventListener("click", agregarFila);

function agregarFila() {
    productoelegido.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td>'+numeroproductocesta+'</td><td>'+unidadescesta+'</td>'
}

function eliminarFila() {
const table = document.getElementById('tablaprueba')
const rowCount = table.rows.length
if (rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado')
else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1)
}  
<table border="1" class="table" id="tablaprueba">
                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>Numero Producto</th>
                                        <th>Unidades</th>                                       
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="agregarFila();">Agregar Fila</button> 
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarFila();">Eliminar Fila</button>                                   
                                </div>



Hasta aqui la parte de Javascript. En el PHP tengo este codigo HTML. Me faltan ideas... :(


<div id="formcesta">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"  id="cestacompra">
            <p>ELIJA NUMERO DE PRODUCTO y UNIDADES</p>           
            <label for="numeroproducto">Numero de Prodcuto:</label><br/>
            <input type="number" id="numeroproducto" name="numeroproducto" /><br />
            <label for="unidades">Unidades de Producto:</label><br/>
            <input type="number" id="unidades" name="unidades" /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="botoncarrito" value="Añadir al carro" />                               
    </form>
<div>



Agradeceria si alguien sabe como es mejor orientar el problema. Muchisimas gracias de antemano.

Para arreglar lo primero debes agregar un event.preventDefault() dentro de la función agregarFila() para que no se ejecute el submit del form.  Y luego mete las lineas de las variables numeroproductocesta y unidadescesta dentro de la misma función, para que se lean cuando se ejecuta y no al cargar la página. Aquí lo tienes funcionando algo mejor: https://jsfiddle.net/3pr0fgbd/

no entiendo que es enfocar un carrito de compra sencillo con PHP y Javascript
